# Unable to get pyrabbit to run

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq

Im working on a little project that running rabbitmq with python, I need a way to access the management api and pull stats, jobs, etc.  I have tried using pyRabbit, but doen't appear to be working unsure why, hoping better programmers might know?  Below I was just following the basic tutorial and readme to perform the very basic task.  My server is up, I'm able to connect outside of python and pyrabbit fine.  I have installed off the dependencies with no luck, at least I think.   Also open to other suggestions for just getting queue size, queues, active clients etc outside of pyRabbit.

'Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user>python

Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import nose

import httplib2

import mock

from pyrabbit.api import Client

import pyrabbit

cl = Client('my.ip.com:15672', 'guest', 'guest')

cl.is_alive()

No JSON object could be decoded - (Not found.) ()

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrabbit\api.py", line 48, in wrapper if self.has_admin_rights:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrabbit\api.py", line 175, in has_admin_right whoami = self.get_whoami()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrabbit\api.py", line 161, in get_whoami whoami = self.http.do_call(path, 'GET')

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrabbit\http.py", line 112, in do_call raise HTTPError(content, resp.status, resp.reason, path, body)
pyrabbit.http.HTTPError: 404 - Object Not Found (None) (whoami) (None)'

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to solve this.  But, this forced me to learn what json is, I used simplejson along with httplib2 and it worked like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

This might be a rabbitmq configuration problem: as it is written here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html, **"guest" user can only connect via localhost:**

> By default, the guest user is prohibited from connecting to the broker remotely; it can only connect over a loopback interface (i.e. localhost). This applies both to AMQP and to any other protocols enabled via plugins. Any other users you create will not (by default) be restricted in this way.
>
> This is configured via the loopback_users item in the configuration file.
>
> If you wish to allow the guest user to connect from a remote host, you should set the loopback_users configuration item to []. A complete >rabbitmq.config which does this would look like:
>
> [{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].